Generating models from old Microsoft sql server 2005 database
I am currently trying to use Django inspectdb to generate models from a very old Microsoft sql server 2005 database. I have not written the database. Now the error I'm getting is that 'SYSDATETIME' is not a recognized built-in function name. So I know it's because that database uses a much older function methods for time and date. How can I solve this problem thanks.

Use the "older" function; GETDATE().
